# PostgreSQL models efficiency to store asset prices - Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I want to store prices of assets in different currencies.

I'm wondering which one of these 2 way below (using Django models) is the most efficient for my PostgreSQL database.

**1st way:**

```
class Price(models.Model):
  asset = models.ForeignKey(Asset, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

  usd = models.FloatField()
  eur = models.FloatField()
  aud = models.FloatField()
  # ...


class AthChangePercentage(models.Model):
  asset = models.ForeignKey(Asset, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

  usd = models.FloatField()
  eur = models.FloatField()
  aud = models.FloatField()
  # ...


class MarketCap(models.Model):
  asset = models.ForeignKey(Asset, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

  usd = models.FloatField()
  eur = models.FloatField()
  aud = models.FloatField()
  # ...
```

Here you can see I use table rows to add different currencies price.

**2nd way:**

```
class Currency(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  symbol = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Price(models.Model):
  asset = models.ForeignKey(Asset, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

  currency = models.ForeignKey(Currency)
  price = models.FloatField()
  #...


class AthChangePercentage(models.Model):
  asset = models.ForeignKey(Asset, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

  currency = models.ForeignKey(Currency)
  ath_change_percentage = models.FloatField()
  #...


class MarketCap(models.Model): 
  asset = models.ForeignKey(Asset, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

  currency = models.ForeignKey(Currency)
  market_cap = models.FloatField()
  #...
```

I cropped the classes because in reality I have around 50 different currencies to handle. Of course there will be multiple assets too.

Which one do you think is the fastest, efficient and less power consuming? Or is there any better way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optimising for database performance or storage may be in your case premature.

However after having experience with writing and working with billing software, I would go with the approach below:

```py
SUPPORTED_CURRENCIES = (("EUR", "Euros", "CZK", "Czech Crown")),  # define your supported currencies


class AmountField(models.DecimalField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not "decimal_places" in kwargs:
            kwargs["decimal_places"] = 4
        if not "max_digits" in kwargs:
            kwargs["max_digits"] = 19
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class CurrencyField(models.CharField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs["max_length"] = 3
        kwargs["choices"] = SUPPORTED_CURRENCIES
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class SomeModel(models.Model):
    amount = PriceField()
    currency = CurrencyField()
```

I would your `price` call `amount`, because `price` is formed by both `amount` and `currency`.

Also you must use `DecimalField` instead of `FloatField` to prevent floating point arithmetic errors.

Comment: So in that case I'd rather use the 2nd way I described in my question. But instead of using a model for the currencies, I use a custom currency field right?

Comment: Yes. There may be no need to deal with complexity of another model.

Comment: Im gonna try and valid your answer if it helps me.